# Remove elements from an array that do not match a regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

In PHP, is there a function or anything else that will remove all elements in an array that do not match a regex.

My regex is this: `preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i', $str)`

My array's come in like this, from a form (they're tags actually)

**Original array from form. Note: evil tags**

```
$arr = array (
    "french-cuisine",
    "french-fries",
    "snack-food",
    "evil*tag!!",
    "fast-food",
    "more~evil*tags"
);
```

**Cleaned array. Note, no evil tags**

```
Array (
    [0] => french-cuisine
    [1] => french-fries
    [2] => snack-food
    [3] => fast-food
)
```

I currently do like this, but is there a better way? Without the loop maybe?

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i', $value)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to filter the array entries that match the regular expression.

```
$cleaned = preg_grep('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i', $arr);
print_r($cleaned);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => french-cuisine
    [1] => french-fries
    [2] => snack-food
    [4] => fast-food
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would not necessarily say it's any better per se, but using regexp and array_filter could look something like this:

```
$data = array_filter($arr , function ($item){
    return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i', $item);
});
```

Where we're returning the result of the preg_match which is either true/false. In this case, it should correctly remove the matched evil tags.

[Here's your eval.in](https://eval.in/190564)

Comment: Does this need a particular version of php to run? I'm on 5.3.13 and keep getting undefined variable $data. The fiddle does not throw an error. But I can see the corrected array.

Comment: `use` is not necessary.

Comment: @Sorin Right. Moving too quickly. Thanks.